# A simple select return an empty table

Tags: mysql, database, select, join

I have this 2 tables:

user:

```
name|id_user|...
john| 1     |...
ales| 2     |...
```

object:

```
name|date|name_user
ball| 11 |john
y   | 22 |ales
```

and I want to get this:

```
name|date|name_user|id_user
ball| 11 |john     | 1
y   | 22 |ales     | 2
```

I try all, also:

```
select * from user,object
where user.name=object.name_user
```

or other way with union, left/right join, but all time I receive an empty table, also this:

```
name|date|name_user|name|id_user|...
```

Why?

Comment: could be you have show hidden char in the name .. try trim the related  ...columns.Which data type you are using for name and name_user?

Comment: thank you for reply, I'm using utf8_encode in all my tables.

Answer (score 0):

One problem you MAY be encountering is that your table name "user" is actually a mysql reserved word.  When you reference that table, try putting backticks around the name ... eg where `user`.name

Comment: Thank you for reply. User and object are eg names not the really.
I think my problem is fields encode, join with other fields work fine, but after exporting file in .txt or .csv format, fields are the same.